# Behavior when a record is deleted from exclusion list and email job uses that record

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, suppressionlist, exclusion-script

We have a use case. We have an email sending job from batch and blast. The records to which the email is sent, are pushed to a Data extension which acts as an exclusion list. Now lets say we have an email called "abc@xyz.com" which is added in this exclusion list. This email is also used in a target DE to which we are going to send email through our automation.

1.The job is paused in between and at this instance if we delete the record from exclusion list, and then the job resumes,  will this email be suppressed or not?

2.Similarly if some other record(not "abc@xyz.com") from source DE is deleted, will it be picked up by the job still?

Also what will be behavior of email job when we add the record to suppression/source DE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscriber list for sending is built in the beginning of a send, which is outlined on this page: '[What Happens When You Click Send](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_what_happens_when_you_click_send.htm&type=5)'. So any changes to sending audience during the paused period would not affect the sending audience. Pausing only affects step 5 the build of the email and sending. As referenced here '[Pause and Resume a Send in Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_pause_resume_send_in_tracking.htm&type=5)' even the email content can not be updated.

> You cannot change any content for the email message when paused. This function only prevents additional sends from occurring until you resume the send.